# React environment variables return undefined despite using REACT_APP prefix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

I have a helper file, api.js whose only job is to query my backend server. Up until recently, it was reading my REACT_APP_API_PATH variable just fine and sending data to the server. However, now I am getting `undefined` when I console log that variable from within my API call.

.env

```
REACT_APP_API_PATH=http://localhost:8080/api
```

api.js

```
import axios from "axios";
const API_PATH = process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH;


export async function apiCall(method, path, data) {
  console.log(API_PATH, process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH); // logs "undefined undefined"
  const res = await axios[method.toLowerCase()](`${API_PATH}${path}`, data);
  return res.data;

}
```

I haven't modified this file, why would this behavior change?

Comment: are you calling `require('dotenv').config()` in your app's top level file?

Comment: No, but according to this post (https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) I don't need to. Create-react-app automatically knows to use any environment variables prefixed with REACT_APP.

Comment: Is the `.env` inside `src` or outside(where it should be)?

Comment: It's outside src

Comment: Old question but I suspect OP is not using `react-scripts`. Needs debugging details